# Equal column height for each row - Genesis Columns

Tags: html, jquery, multiple-columns

This jQuery script creates equal column heights on all columns in a webpage. How do I modify the jQuery to equal column height for each row.
i.e. there are four halves with varying heights.

jQuery Equal Height Columns

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var highestBox = 0;
    $('.one-half').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > highestBox)
            highestBox = $(this).height();
    });

    $('.one-half').height(highestBox);
});
```

HTML columns

```
<div class="one-half first">
    Eyebrow Tidy: $18.00
    Eyebrow Shape: $24.00
    Lip: $12.00
    Chin: $15.00
</div>
<div class="one-half">
    Side facial: $15.00
    Underarm: $25.00
    Full arm: $35.00
    Half arm: $22.00
    Chest: $46.00
    Back: $40.00
</div>
<div class="one-half first">
    Lip: $12.00
    Chin: $15.00
</div>
<div class="one-half">
    Back: $40.00
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do

Comment: Make the columns adjust height depending on row.  [link](http://s8.postimg.org/aqm088dh1/Screen_Shot_2015_12_03_at_8_07_03_PM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you mean by column and row. I will assume you got some CSS to put `.one-half`-divs next to each other.

You will need a wrapping container for each row

```css
.row {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}
.one-half {
  margin: 1em;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="one-half first">
    Eyebrow Tidy: $18.00
    Eyebrow Shape: $24.00
    Lip: $12.00
    Chin: $15.00
  </div>
  <div class="one-half">
    Side facial: $15.00
    Underarm: $25.00
    Full arm: $35.00
    Half arm: $22.00
    Chest: $46.00
    Back: $40.00
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="row">
  <div class="one-half first">
    Lip: $12.00
    Chin: $15.00
  </div>
  <div class="one-half">
    Back: $40.00
  </div>
</div>
```

The height of the `row` container should go with the highest column `one-half` automatically. No need for any calculation.

Comment: the `.one-half` heights in yellow are still different. Can we create them equal heights?